# Autogenerate wordpress shortcodes using array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, for-loop, shortcode

I was create a shortcode which automatically generate shortcodes with given array key and value. Function names does not generate dynamically.

Note: Array KEY = ShortcodeName and Value = Wordpress Option field.

```
add_shortcode("auto_gen", "auto_gen");
function auto_gen() {
    $a = array(
        "get_address"       =>  "mg_admin_address",
        "get_phone"         =>  "mg_admin_phone",
        "get_fax"           =>  "mg_admin_fax",
        "get_email"         =>  "mg_admin_email",
        "get_hrs_mon"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_mon_frd",
        "get_hrs_sat"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_sat"
    );
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if(has_shortcode($k)) {
            echo "<br>Found: ". $k;
        } else {
            add_shortcode($k,  $k. "_init");
            function $k. "_init"() {
                return get_option[$v, ''];
            }
        }
        add_shortcode();
        echo $k ." -> ". $v. "<br />";
    }
}
```

There is any possible way to do this.

**NOTE:**

> Here, get_address array key is a shortcode. And it is dynamically generate when It pass though loop. get_address is changable. If I change get_address with get_user_address then get_user_address generate generated. "get_address", "get_phone" are CHANGABLE at END LEVEL.

Developer also generate shortcodes to access created wp_options useing get_options, simply pushing elements in array. e.g. "shortcode_name" => "option_name"

Comment: Please don't [multipost the same question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159153/autogenerate-wordpress-shortcodes-using-array/).

Answer (score 1):

The function `add_shortcode` has a [third parameter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78204/12615) that contains the current shortcode, so the same callback can be used multiple times:

```
$all = array( 'address', 'phone', 'fax', 'email', 'hrs_mon', 'hrs_sat' );

foreach ( $all as $s )
    add_shortcode( "get_$s", 'general_shortcode' );

function general_shortcode( $atts, $content = '', $shortcode = '' )
{
    switch( $shortcode )
    {
        case 'get_address':
            $return = 'ADDRESS';
        break;
        case 'get_phone':
            $return = 'PHONE';
        break;
        default:
            $return = 'OTHER SHORTCODES';
        break;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Another possibility:

```
Class AllShortcodes{
    private $all = array(
        "get_address"       =>  "mg_admin_address",
        "get_phone"         =>  "mg_admin_phone",
        "get_fax"           =>  "mg_admin_fax",
        "get_email"         =>  "mg_admin_email",
        "get_hrs_mon"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_mon_frd",
        "get_hrs_sat"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_sat"
    );

    public function __construct() {
        foreach ( $this->all as $key => $value )
            add_shortcode( $key, array( $this, 'general_shortcode' ) );
    }

    public function general_shortcode( $atts, $content = '', $shortcode = '' )
    {
        return $this->all[$shortcode];
    }
}
$myShortcodes = new AllShortcodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
add_shortcode("auto_gen", "auto_gen");
    function auto_gen() {
        $a = array(
            "get_address"       =>  "mg_admin_address",
            "get_phone"         =>  "mg_admin_phone",
            "get_fax"           =>  "mg_admin_fax",
            "get_email"         =>  "mg_admin_email",
            "get_hrs_mon"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_mon_frd",
            "get_hrs_sat"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_sat"
        );
        foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
            if(has_shortcode($v,$k)) {
                echo "<br>Found: ". $k;
            } else {
                add_shortcode($k,  $k."_init");
                $func =$k."_init";
        $func($v); 
            }
            echo $k ." -> ". $v. "<br />";
        }
    }
     function get_address_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
     function get_phone_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
    function get_fax_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
    function get_email_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
    function get_hrs_mon_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
    function get_hrs_sat_init ($v) { 
                    return get_option($v, '');
    }
```